# Powershell does not let me open firebase CLI

Tags: powershell, firebase-cli

Powershell won't let me open firebase, every time i enter the command "firebase login". comes the question "how to open the file" ihc never had problems opening firebase with powershell before and now i get this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKZH8.png)

Comment: What's the output of `Get-Command firebase`?

Comment: What happens if you select a browser? Does it work?

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen  this is what comes out when i enter this command "Application     firebase                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Windows\system32\firebase"

Comment: Kato how do you mean open a new browser?